# No puedo editar con crontab -e y antes si podía

Tags: crontab, solaris

Estoy trabajando en una maquina con las siguientes características:
SunOS 5.9 Generic_Virtual sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320

Hace unos meses podía editar el crontab con `crontab -e` y conseguí añadir la siguiente línea:

`* * * * * /opt/webMethods3/david/monitorizarWM.sh`, la cual puedo ver con el comando `crontab -l`.

El problema es que ahora quiero editar el crontab de nuevo y usando `crontab -e` y no puedo.
Os dejo la diferencia con cada uno de los 2 comandos anteriores:

```
/opt/webMethods3/david> crontab -l
* * * * * /opt/webMethods3/david/monitorizarWM.sh
/opt/webMethods3/david> crontab -e
50
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a saber que puede ocurrir?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Despues de muchos intentos, he ejecutado el siguiente comando `export EDITOR=vi` y ahora ya se abre bien y puedo editarlo.